# Why is Java calling the locale en-US, when clearly the system is set to en-AU?

Tags: java, macos, locale

Our build machines for OSX are running a mix of 10.10 and 10.11. During the initial machine setup for the build machines, as for my own machine, Australian English was selected as the locale. My own machine is running 10.12, so that is one potential difference.

When I ask `locale` what Locale I'm running, I get exactly what I'd expect.

```
m-matsurika:~ tester$ locale
LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

However, when I am inside Java, the Locale is inexplicably set to US English:

```
m-matsurika:~ tester$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Java::JavaUtil::Locale.getDefault.toLanguageTag
=> "en-US"
```

But this is only happening for the build machines. For my own machine, the result is "en-AU", exactly what I'd expect. Even though all machines were, as far as I know, set up the same way.

How is this possible?

Additional attempts to poke at the issue:

```
m-matsurika:~ tester$ LANG=en_AU ruby -e 'puts Java::JavaUtil::Locale.getDefault.toLanguageTag'
en-US
m-matsurika:~ tester$ LC_ALL=en_AU ruby -e 'puts Java::JavaUtil::Locale.getDefault.toLanguageTag'
en-US

m-hisui:~ tester$ LANG=ja_JP ruby -e 'puts Java::JavaUtil::Locale.getDefault.toLanguageTag'
en-US
m-hisui:~ tester$ LC_ALL=ja_JP ruby -e 'puts Java::JavaUtil::Locale.getDefault.toLanguageTag'
en-US
```

Additional system info:

```
m-matsurika:~ tester$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

**Further investigation:**

I wrote a test program to fetch the macOS locale, and it displayed en_AU. Seeing this, I dug up the source code for the Java launcher itself to see how it behaved. After spending half a day condensing that down to a runnable test program, I found that this test problem *also* displays en_AU.

I also tested multiple Javas. 1.8.0_92, 1.8.0_112 and 9 all behave the same, showing en_US once you're inside Java. The source I was reading was for 92, but that appeared to return the right value.

So how does Java determine the Locale it sets, if it's not from the code I was able to find in the JDK source code?